# Is the converse of divisibility of $a\mid b \land a\mid c \implies a\mid (b+c)$ always true?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

If $a\mid b$ and $a\mid c$ then $a\mid(b+c)$ where $a$ and $b$ are non zero and belong to $Z$.
But does the converse hold true?
E.g. $2\mid 8$ but it does not divide $5$ or $3$. Of course we can express $8$ differently i.e. $4+4$ and then it holds.
But I was wondering in the generality if $a\mid x$ then can $x$ **always** be expressed in sums of numbers that are divisible by $a$? Of course in case that $x$ is not prime.
**Update (thanks to @EricTowers)**
Basically the question is if it can be proven that for all ,∈ ℤ, if |, then there exist ,∈ℤ such that =+, |, and |.

Comment: Do you mean *natural* numbers?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos: I believe the original theorem is for Z

Comment: Since $a|a$, we need to know if you allow $0$ or negative numbers for $b$ and $c$.

Comment: @EricTowers: I updated the post. Is that ok now?

Comment: @DietrichBurde: Yes but that is not a proof

Comment: $x = a + (x-a)$ ...

Comment: A proof for which claim?

Comment: @DietrichBurde: for the converse of the theorem

Comment: @MartinR: Ah is it that trivial then?

Comment: The converse is false. No proof needed, only a counterexample.

Comment: You are going to get many confused answers because you *say* you want the converse, but you don't actually want the converse.  What you want is "For all $a, d \in \mathbb{Z}$, if $a | d$, then there exist $b, c \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $d = b+c$, $a|b$, and $a|c$."

Comment: @EricTowers: Yes, I couldn't formalize it like you have now. Could I use it for the post?

Comment: @Jim What's the point? Martin R.'s comment says everything that there is to be said.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos: I don't know to be honest. That sounds like a tautology not a proof. But may be I am just confused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me clarify this a bit. Let $a,b$, and $x$ be integers.

**Original statement** (true): if $x|a$ and $x|b$, then $x|(a+b)$.

**Converse statement** (false): if $x|(a+b)$, then $x|a$ and $a|b$.

The first statement is true of course, but the second statement is false. In fact, you already gave a counterexample: take $x=2$, $a=5$, $b=3$.

The other statement you hinted at would be the following, which is different from either of the first two.

**New statement**: if $x|y$, then we can find integers $a$ and $b$ such that $y=a+b$, $x|a$, and $x|b$.

This is true because we can take $a=y$ and $b=0$.

Comment: Thank you for helping me clarifying this.